# Sudoku type grid generator

Tags: java, performance, sudoku

I'm trying to make a program which prints different sized grids (n by n grids). 
These grids cannot have the same number in any column or row (like a Sudoku). 
My `bruteSolve()` method runs through every combination and then `isValid()` checks if the rows and columns add up & multiply up to a certain number too - if they do, then the program prints the grid.

However, this program takes too long and I want one where I could do say, 10 * 10 grids fairly quickly. How would I be able to change the code so it does it much faster?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MagicSquareSolver2 {

static ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

static int n;

static int [] [] grid;

static int count;


public static void main (String [] args){

    n = 4;  

    grid = new int [n] [n] ;

    bruteSolve(0,0,n);
}

public static void bruteSolve(int a, int b, int n){

    for  (int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
        grid [a][b] = i;
        if (b==n-1 && a==n-1){ 
            if (isValid(grid)){count++;
            System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));System.out.println(count);
        }
        }
        else if (b==n-1){
            bruteSolve(a+1,0,n);
        }
        else{
            bruteSolve(a, b+1,n);
        }
    }

}



public static boolean isValid (int [] [] grid) {

    int factorial = 1;
    int fibonacci = 0;
    int totalX1 = 1;
    int totalY1 = 1;
    int totalX2 = 0;
    int totalY2 = 0;

    for (int i=n; i>0; i--){
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }

    for (int i=n; i>0; i--){
        fibonacci = fibonacci +i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            totalY1= totalY1 * grid[i][j]; //checks all columns
            totalX1= totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
            totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
            totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
        }
        if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) { return false; }
        totalX1 = 1;
        totalY1 = 1;
        totalX2 = 0;
        totalY2 = 0;
    }

    return true;

}

}
```

Comment: You should look at the papers in this answer:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/106571/sudoku-puzzle-part-1-sudoku-class/106647#106647

Comment: you could use `*=`  and `+=` to make your code less verbose.

Answer (score 5):

A couple of things:

### Indentation

Indentation seems a little off in your question. Is this because of formatting issues when copy and pasting from your IDE, or is it your code? Most IDEs have a format function that formats the code for you. In eclipse, that is found in `Source` -> `Format` or the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+F`.

### Spacing

You have what I call overspacing:

> ```
> static int [] [] grid;
> ```

and underspacing:

> ```
> for  (int i=1; i<n+1; i++){
> ```

Again, formatting in an IDE will usually fix that.

After formatting, your code will look like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MagicSquareSolver2 {

    static ArrayList<Integer> numbers;

    static int n;

    static int[][] grid;

    static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        n = 4;

        grid = new int[n][n];

        bruteSolve(0, 0, n);
    }

    public static void bruteSolve(int a, int b, int n) {

        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            grid[a][b] = i;
            if (b == n - 1 && a == n - 1) {
                if (isValid(grid)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            } else if (b == n - 1) {
                bruteSolve(a + 1, 0, n);
            } else {
                bruteSolve(a, b + 1, n);
            }
        }

    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid) {

        int factorial = 1;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int totalX1 = 1;
        int totalY1 = 1;
        int totalX2 = 0;
        int totalY2 = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            fibonacci = fibonacci + i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                totalY1 = totalY1 * grid[i][j]; // checks all columns
                totalX1 = totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
                totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
                totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
            }
            if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial
                    || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) {
                return false;
            }
            totalX1 = 1;
            totalY1 = 1;
            totalX2 = 0;
            totalY2 = 0;
        }

        return true;

    }

}
```

After some edits in spacing that are not fixed by the IDE:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MagicSquareSolver2 {

    static ArrayList<Integer> numbers;
    static int n;
    static int[][] grid;
    static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        n = 4;
        grid = new int[n][n];
        bruteSolve(0, 0, n);
    }

    public static void bruteSolve(int a, int b, int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
            grid[a][b] = i;
            if (b == n - 1 && a == n - 1) {
                if (isValid(grid)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            } else if (b == n - 1) {
                bruteSolve(a + 1, 0, n);
            } else {
                bruteSolve(a, b + 1, n);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid) {
        int factorial = 1;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int totalX1 = 1;
        int totalY1 = 1;
        int totalX2 = 0;
        int totalY2 = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            fibonacci = fibonacci + i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                totalY1 = totalY1 * grid[i][j]; // checks all columns
                totalX1 = totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
                totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
                totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
            }
            if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial
                    || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) {
                return false;
            }
            totalX1 = 1;
            totalY1 = 1;
            totalX2 = 0;
            totalY2 = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

### `static` variables

No, no, no. Rarely should you use static variables, such as a `public static final` class constant, or something that needs to be `static` when there is no other option available. You can easily redesign your code to not need `static` variables:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MagicSquareSolver2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 4;
        int[][] grid = new int[n][n];
        bruteSolve(0, 0, n, grid);
    }

    public static void bruteSolve(int a, int b, int n, int[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 1, count = 0; i < n + 1; i++) {
            grid[a][b] = i;
            if (b == n - 1 && a == n - 1) {
                if (isValid(grid, n)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            } else if (b == n - 1) {
                bruteSolve(a + 1, 0, n, grid);
            } else {
                bruteSolve(a, b + 1, n, grid);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid, int n) {
        int factorial = 1;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int totalX1 = 1;
        int totalY1 = 1;
        int totalX2 = 0;
        int totalY2 = 0;

        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }
        for (int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
            fibonacci = fibonacci + i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                totalY1 = totalY1 * grid[i][j]; // checks all columns
                totalX1 = totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
                totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
                totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
            }
            if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial
                    || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) {
                return false;
            }
            totalX1 = 1;
            totalY1 = 1;
            totalX2 = 0;
            totalY2 = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

What I did with your variables:

1. `static ArrayList<Integer> numbers;`

   You didn't even use this...
2. `static int n;`

   Just simply put this in the main method, and added a `int n` argument to your `isValid()` method.
3. `static int[][] grid;`

   Just simply put this in the main method, and added a `int[][] grid` argument into your `bruteSolve()` method.
4. `static int count;`

   You only really need this in your `bruteSolve()` method; actually just the `for` loop, so I just put it there.

### Naming

What's `a`? How about `b`? What is `n`? Why are they one-letter names?

One-letter variable names are not good, as they are confusing to understand. The only place you should use them is, for example, a `for` loop counter.

Change:

1. `a` into `num1`
2. `b` into `num2`
3. `n` into `size` (or, optional: remove the n variable completely, and directly use either `grid.size` or the number itself, or change it into a constant, as I will do)

### Final Code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MagicSquareSolver2 {

    public static final int SIZE = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
        bruteSolve(0, 0, grid);
    }

    public static void bruteSolve(int num1, int num2, int[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 1, count = 0; i < SIZE + 1; i++) {
            grid[num1][num2] = i;
            if (num2 == SIZE - 1 && num1 == SIZE - 1) {
                if (isValid(grid)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
                    System.out.println(count);
                }
            } else if (num2 == SIZE - 1) {
                bruteSolve(num1 + 1, 0, grid);
            } else {
                bruteSolve(num1, num2 + 1, grid);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid) {
        int factorial = 1;
        int fibonacci = 0;
        int totalX1 = 1;
        int totalY1 = 1;
        int totalX2 = 0;
        int totalY2 = 0;

        for (int i = SIZE; i > 0; i--) {
            factorial = factorial * i;
        }
        for (int i = SIZE; i > 0; i--) {
            fibonacci = fibonacci + i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
                totalY1 = totalY1 * grid[i][j]; // checks all columns
                totalX1 = totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
                totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
                totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
            }
            if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial
                    || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) {
                return false;
            }
            totalX1 = 1;
            totalY1 = 1;
            totalX2 = 0;
            totalY2 = 0;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Looks good now!

Comment: These are good hints, however I think you missed the main point of the question - can the performance be improved and how?

Comment: @Sva.Mu I am currently thinking about it; be patient! Also, I can't seem to understand your each line of code and what it does. Just to confirm, your code will check a `n` by `n` board to see if each row and column has any duplicate numbers, correct?

Comment: This is not "my" question :-) but I think this is what OP meant, yes.

Comment: @Sva.Mu also, from what I can see when I run the program, is that it generates all possible combinations of a `n` x `n` Sudoku Grid, taking into account of all the Sudoku rules: "each row, column and box may not contain the digits 1-9 (or 1 to `x` in this case) more than once".

Comment: I guess we have a misunderstanding here as the question was posted by Hisham, not by me - I just read your answer and noticed it doesn't really answer the performance question.

Comment: @Sva.Mu Oh ok, sorry. My mistake.